# excel formula to get the latest timestamp of latest updated cell in a particular row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I need a formula in MS Excel to get the last updated timestamp everytime any cell in a particular row is updated.I am using
 `=if($2:$2="","",NOW())` 
but when one cell is updated, every cell even of other row having similar formula is updated with the latest time-stamp. What can be the problem?

I need only formula not a macro/excel program.

Comment: From my understanding it would have to be in VBA. As every time an cell is updated all formula will run because of Excel calculation options. So unless you use VBA I do not think it is possible. But please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Sam - You're not wrong. `NOW()` is a volatile function that will recalculate  whenever any value is changed within the workbook. Unless the formula's result is reverted to its underlying value (removing the formula), the `NOW()` function will continue to recalculate. Typically this is handled with a `Worksheet_Change` event macro.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a VBA macro in the worksheet change event. You can easily input a timestamp as a string into your row depending on the row of the changed cell. **There is no formula that can do what you're asking**.

To get to the worksheet change event, go to File, and then Options. Then go to Customize Ribbon. Check the box next to Developer in the column on the right. Under the newly added Developer tab in the Ribbon, select Visual Basic on the far left. Find you worksheet in the Project window on the left hand side of the Editor that opens up. You may need to expand your Workbook and a folder called Excel Objects. Double click on the sheet to get to its code. A window will open with two drop downs at the top. On the left, go to Worksheet. On the Right, select Change. In between `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` and `End Sub`, you can add the code that will run whenever the worksheet is changed.

This is the code you would use, replacing "5" in Cells() with the column you want to put a timestamp in.

```
Dim i As Integer
i = Target.Row

Dim t As String
t = VBA.Now

Cells(i, 5) = t
```

Answer (score -1):

If the cell to contain the timestamp is B3 and the cell to watch is C3 the formula is:
=IF(C3<>"",IF(B3="",NOW(),B3),"")

Comment: That does not help as if they put that everywhere then as we have said in the comments above. The NOW() function will update everytime any change is made